# Selecting values from a DOM / XML using Jquery selectors

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a following structered DOM result, getting after a POST event:

```
<root>
  <config>
      // Some inner tree
  </config>
  <test>
    <test testValue="0">
      <id>90</id>
      <time>false</time>
      <config>
        <config1>1</config1>
      </config>
      <languages>
        <language id="en" isDefault="true" >
          <test22 text=""  />
          <test23 text=""  />
        </language>
      </languages>
      <answers>
        <answer>
          <id>201</id>
          <Texts>
            <Text localeId="en" Text="Yes" />
          </Texts>
        </answer>
        <answer>
          <id>202</id>
          <Texts>
            <Text localeId="en"Text="No" />
          </Texts>
        </answer>
      </answers>
    </test>
  </test>
</root>
```

The above DOM returns after calling $.get(url, function(XML)), and I am able to do these:

Getting the Text (Yes, No), and id (201, 202) with the following code.

```
    $(XML).find("answer").each(function(){
        var textValue = $(this).find("Text").attr("Text");
        var idValue = $(this).find("id").text();
    });
```

But I couldn't find the correct combination to get id (90) e.g. following didn't work:

```
$(XML).find("test").children().attr("id");
```

It's quite frustrating to debug jquery. I installed Firefox addon, Firequery, and saved the DOM into a file with html extension, but Firequery didn't allow me to chain the functions like $.find("id").text(); . What is the way to get the id value 90 from DOM with jquery? What are you using to debug the jquery while working with DOM and XML files like in the snippet?

Comment: try: `$(XML).find("test").children().find("test").find("id").text();`

Comment: You have a `test` node containing other `test` nodes -- I'm not sure if it's invalid XML (since XHTML allows such things), but it's certainly bad practice for structured data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`id` is not an attribute but an element, so you sould select it like you selected `text`. To get 90, ask for `.text()` on the `id` element.

```
$(XML).find('test').children('id').text();
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/Mikey/FjnTS/

Comment: I figured out how to debug with Firebug + Firequery. So, this is the answer to get the 90: $(XML).find("test").find("id").first().text(). This is also possible $("test", XML).find("id")first().text(). People says different things for the comparison of both of their performance, but I couldn't make a two find() chain in the Firebug console, and three selector filter in jsfiddle. Thanks for the jsfiddle link!

Answer (score 0):

"id" isn't an attribute of a node, it's the content of a node. Try searching for `testValue="0"`:

```
$idnode = $('test[testValue="0"]').find('id'); // a jQuery object
idvalue = $idnode.text(); // the string "90"
idnumber = parseInt(idvalue,10); // the number 90
```